# Spring - SessionBean Instance is being shared by multiple users in java

Tags: java, spring, session

I have a Java Spring Bean called SessionBean that is being shared by multiple users.  When a new user accesses my application, an instance of the SessionBean is created.  This bean is meant to hold a user's id and privilege information that determines what they can see on my app.  However, if a second user access the application at the same time the first user is using it, the created bean is overridden by the second user's credentials and both users use those overridden credentials.  How do I make it so that each users SessionBean is independent of other users?

MainController.java

```
package com.trac.controller;

import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.trac.verification.*;
import com.trac.bean.SessionBean;

@Controller
public class MainController {

private CompanyOrgVerification org = new CompanyOrgVerification();

@Autowired
private SessionBean session;
@Autowired
private RacfGroupData racfGroup;

//returns the agent search page
@RequestMapping(URIConstants.WELCOME_PAGE)
public ModelAndView welcome(HttpServletRequest request){ 

    this.session = new SessionBean();

    String userId = request.getHeader("x-user");
    System.out.println(userId.trim());
    session.setUserId(userId.trim());

    if( racfGroup.getRacfGroups(session.getUserId()) ){
        session.setPermission("INFOA", "U"); //Granting the default permissions to anyone with access to the application.
        return new ModelAndView("index");
    }else{
        ModelAndView error = new ModelAndView();
        error.setViewName("error");
        return error;   

    }
}


//returns the agent profile page
@RequestMapping(value = URIConstants.PROFILE_PAGE )
public ModelAndView profile(HttpServletRequest request){
     Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
     String profileEntityNo = "";
     for(int i=0; i<cookies.length; i++){

         String cookieName = cookies[i].getName().toUpperCase();

         switch(cookieName){
            case "ENTITYNO": profileEntityNo = cookies[i].getValue().toString().trim();
                break;
            case "STATE": cookies[i].getValue().toString().trim();
                break;
            case "NAME": cookies[i].getValue().replace("%20", " ").replace("%2C", ",").trim();
                break;
            case "DISTRICT": cookies[i].getValue().toString().trim();
                break;
         }
     }
    if( session.hasAccessToApp() ){ //check if user is authorized to access page
        int structureNo = 3; //company org structure number
        String structureCd = "ORG";
        org.setSessionBean(session); 
        org.setProfilePrivileges(profileEntityNo, structureCd, structureNo);
        this.setSessionBean( org.getSessionBean() );

        ModelAndView profile = new ModelAndView();
        profile.setViewName("profile");
        profile.addObject("userId", session.getUserId());
        profile.addObject("privileges", session.getProfilePrivileges() ); 
        profile.addObject("accessType", session.getAccessType() );

        return profile; 
    }else{
        return new ModelAndView("error");
    }
}

public SessionBean getSessionBean(){
    return session;
}
public void setSessionBean(SessionBean session){
    this.session = session;
}
public RacfGroupData getRacfGroup(){
    return racfGroup;
}
public void setRacfGroup(RacfGroupData racfGroup){
    this.racfGroup = racfGroup;
}

}
```

SessionBean.java

```
package com.trac.bean;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ScopedProxyMode;


@Component
@Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS ) 
public class SessionBean {

private String userId;
private String permission = "";
private final int grant_InfoA = 0;
private final int grant_Trac = 1;
private final int grant_Term = 2;
private final int grant_Conf = 3;
private final int grant_Mark = 4;
private boolean[] profilePrivileges = new boolean [ 5 ]; //holds the user privileges for a profile
private String[] accessType = new String[5];

public void setPermission(String permissionValue, String type){
    try{
        permission = permissionValue;
        setPrivileges(type);
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Exception caught in SessionBean - setPermission. "+e.toString());
    }
}

public void setPrivileges(String type){
 try{
      System.out.println("***Permission String: " + this.permission + "***");
    //Default Permission  
      if(permission.equals("INFOA")){
          profilePrivileges[grant_InfoA] = true;
          accessType[grant_InfoA] = type;
          System.out.println("***Granted access to the application***");
      }
    //Subsidy Tab Permission  
      else if(permission.equals("TRAC")){
          profilePrivileges[grant_Trac] = true;
          accessType[grant_Trac] = type;
          System.out.println("***Granted access to Trac subsidy***");
      }
    //Termination Tab Permission
      else if(permission.equals("TERM")){
          profilePrivileges[grant_Term] = true;
          accessType[grant_Term] = type;
          System.out.println("***Granted access to termination info***");
      }
    //Conference Tab Permission  
      else if(permission.equals("CONF")){
          profilePrivileges[grant_Conf] = true;
          accessType[grant_Conf] = type;
          System.out.println("***Granted access to conference info***");
      }
    //Service/Transfer & Term Tabs Permission
      else if(permission.equals("MARK")){
          profilePrivileges[grant_Mark] = true;
          accessType[grant_Mark] = type;
          System.out.println("***Granted access to Service/Transfer and Term tabs***");
      }
      else{
        System.out.println("No privileges set.  Permission string is: "
            + permission);
      }
    }catch (Exception e){
      System.out.println("^^^^ Exception caught in SessionBean."
          + "setPrivileges ^^^^\n" + e.toString());
    }
}

public String getUserId() {
    return userId;
}
public void setUserId(String userId) {
    this.userId = userId.toUpperCase();
}
public boolean hasAccessToApp(){
    if( profilePrivileges[grant_InfoA] == true){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    } 
}

public boolean[] getProfilePrivileges(){
    return profilePrivileges;
}

public String[] getAccessType(){
    return accessType; 
}

}
```

Comment: What do you think `this.session = new SessionBean();` does?

Comment: I was having a problem with the privileges array being filled with multiple users individual privileges.  Say user A logs in and is allowed to see TRAC but not, TERM or CONF.  When user B logged in, who can see TERM but not TRAC, then the session bean privilege array would be true for both TRAC and TERM allowing both users to see data they shouldn't.  By using thus.session = new SessionBean() I created a new session whenever someone accessed the app, preventing privileges from being shared.

Comment: Forget about your use case for a second. If you create the object yourself, how will Spring be involved?

Comment: It isn't, but the underlying problem remains the same.  How do I make it so that a User's SessionBean remains independent of other's

Comment: Leave your `session` field as `@Autowired`, don't reassign it, and then just use it.

Comment: Didn't work and I am back to having the privileges array remaining populated with other user's data when it shouldn't.

Comment: `org` is an instance field in a singleton scoped bean. All threads share it.

Comment: I tried moving the CompanyOrgVerification org variable instantiation to the profile function but that didn't do anything.  The application is still replacing the SessionBean credentials with the second user's and the privilege array is still remaining populated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this really isn't the solution I was looking for but it got the job done.  What I did was in the profile() function of the MainController class I re-pulled the userId from the Header, like what I did in the welcome() function and reset it in the session.  I then created a new function in the SessionBean that reset the privileges and accessType arrays and called it in the profile() function of the MainController.  This allowed me to pull the correct privileges for a user without any cross contamination from other user privileges.

If anyone has a better solution I am more than happy to hear them.